# how to check if a checkbox exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

The check box's exist for each row. the table is created by PHP and I need a way to check if the check box exists. when they are created they are given the ID of checkbox_(an incrementing number).

This is what I have so far, but it does not work on checking if the element exists.

```
var check = true;
var todelete = "";
var counter = 0;

//check if box exisits and record id and post
while(check)
{
    if ($("#Checkbox_"+counter).length > 0)
    {
    todelete = todelete + $("#Checkbox_"+counter).value;
    counter = counter + 1;
    }
    else
    {
    check = false;
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
 if ($("Checkbox_"+counter))
 if (document.getElementById("tbody").value == null)
```

Update:

Even with the # symbol or if i do it by javascripts element ID - when I debug the DOM, it hits the while, then the if, adds the value to todelete, adds 1 to the counter, then it goes back to the while, then hits the if

Then bounces back up to the while without even going into the if or the else???

this I do not understand, then it just bounces up and down between the two lines and crash's the browser?

Update2:

I needed to .tostring() the counter when adding it to the string for an element id. problem solved

Comment: Looks your missing a `#` when checking for the ID. Make it look like this `$("#Checkbox_"+counter)`

Comment: HTML has no `Checkbox_<number>` element. So that's probably your problem. But as you didn't show your HTML, we cannot give a definite advice.

Comment: why don't you work with a css-class and use the `.`-selector to gather all checkboxes?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
if ($("#Checkbox_"+counter).length > 0)
```

I'm assuming that 'Checkbox_0' is an ID, so I've added the # symbol. If it's the name of the checkbox, you can use

```
if ($("input[name='Checkbox_"+counter+"']").length > 0);
```

[edit]Also, you should check to make sure you do / don't need the capital 'C'.

Comment: @FelixKling You don't need the # symbol?

Answer (score 5):

You can use for "checkbox exists in this case"

```
if ($("#Checkbox_"+counter).length > 0) {
  //checkbox exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($("#Checkbox_"+counter).length) > 0) {
...

//Or something more generalized
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){
  return jQuery(this).length>0;
}
//then, if you have valid selector
if ($("#Checkbox_"+counter).exists()){
    //do something here if our selected element exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if document.getElementById(name) do not exist
// document.getElementById(name).value generate already an error

if (document.getElementById(name) != null) {
// you code if checkbox exist
}
```